# Progress bar for Upload browser Base

Tags: youtube-api

I'm looking for a way to show the progress of the upload to the user because it's very long.

I try to use ajax for post the file but that doesn't work.
The file seems uploaded but in fact i never see the video on my youtube channel and i have nothing in the complete callback.

I see lot of topics talk about this, but they are very old (2009/2010) so i hoped that one of you had found a solution.

Also i can't use the experimental api v3 because my app is for a big brand who need something very stable,
neither the iframe because i need to design the upload form.

Thanks a lot.

Gwen

Answer (score 0):

I'm anxious to achieve the same thing, but I don't think it's possible right now. I asked the same question, [YouTube API Browser-Based Upload with Ajax for Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146803/youtube-api-browser-based-upload-with-ajax-for-progress-bar), and got a response from someone on the YouTube team at Google. However, their suggestions didn't pan out for me, but maybe it'll work for you.

Comment: effectively I saw this post but the suggestions can't work for me. (api v3 and widget).